# Command line tools to manipulate CSVs

Tags: unix, csv, command-line-interface

I have quite a big CSV file looking like this:

```
id,date,user,points
32,2006-10-10T15:43:00Z,alice,5
37,2006-10-10T20:13:54Z,bob,12
38,2006-10-10T20:44:53Z,alice,7
39,2006-10-10T20:55:50Z,john,4
40,2006-10-10T20:59:01Z,john,8
42,2006-10-11T02:10:01Z,alice,16
....
```

I was wondering it there is any command line utilities to manipulate this csv to build a sort of pivot table from this data, getting quickly the total number of points per user for example.

I know this is totally feasible writing a small script but knowing how powerful `awk` or `grep` are, I was expecting a similar solution for this type of data manipulation.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Perl comes to mind for its associative array or hash.  But I think awk can do it too, especially together with grep.  Where are you stuck on this?  Can you not find something similar and modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ftable](https://github.com/tlopo/ftable/blob/master/README.md), it's a monolithic perl script with no external dependencies.

Donwload, make it executable and run. very easy.

Answer (score 0):

[Tabulator](https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/tabulator) is a set of unix command line tools to work with delimited files that have header lines. Suppose your file is called `test.csv.` Then

```
tblred -uk user -c'sum_points=sum(points)' alice.csv
```

produces

```
user,sum_points
alice,28.0
bob,12.0
john,12.0
```